# Create Order Manually from virtuemart admin panel

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I want to create orders manually from virtue mart admin panel.Suppose one client call me to buy a product so i can be able to enter his phone number, email product he want to buy and other credential. Is there any way of doing this. I am using Joomla 2.5 And virtuemart 2.0.8 .

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are out of luck for VM 2.0, there are not any manual order entry extensions that I know of. However, you can easily just create the order through the front end. If you turn on anonymous checkout, you can simply place the order as if you were the customer.